# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am getting the following warning when trying to add data to a session (and checking if it already exists).

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

How can I fix this?

The code it is referring to:

```
if(isset($_GET['product']) && !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}
```

I only get this warning when adding the first product on a cleaned browser. When I remove it and add another product the warning is gone. Same if I add a second product.

Comment: it seems `$_SESSION['product']` dosen't contain any data. Try to print `$_SESSION['product']`

Comment: `$_SESSION['product']` is null

Comment: may i know which one return an array $_SESSION['product'] or $_GET['product'] ?

Comment: Add a `$_SESSION["product"] = $_SESSION["product"]?:[]` before the if to initialize the array. Otherwise you'll never add anything to it with this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warining says it all. This param is null:

```
 $_SESSION['product']
```

Make sure it is set before you use it. Example:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['product']) && isset($_GET['product']) &&  !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])){
        $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$_SESSION['product']` is empty.
Try this,

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['product']) && isset($_GET['product']) && !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

check if the value is set before use it with isset and use is_array to check if a given variable is an array.

```
if(isset($_GET['product']) && is_set($_SESSION['product']) && is_array($_SESSION['product']) && !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should always apply check for array

```
isset( $_SESSION['product']) in your is condition before & condition
```